# How to set a Region using a Rect

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to set a region in this way:

```
val region = Region()
region.set(Rect(0, 459, 1080, 0))
```

I also tried:

```
val region = Rect(5, 459, 1080, 5).toRegion()
```

Unfortunately, both of them don't work. It seems the region is always 0. In fact, the method `region.bounds` should return the `Rect` I've set before, instead it returns `Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why the method `set()` of the `Region` class does not work, but I've found a way to solve the problem. I created an extension function:

```
fun Rect.toRightRegion() : Region {
        val region = Region()
        val path = Path()
        path.addRect(RectF(this.left.toFloat(), this.top.toFloat(), this.right.toFloat(), this.bottom.toFloat()), Path.Direction.CW)
        val rectF = RectF()
        path.computeBounds(rectF, true)
        region.setPath(path, Region(rectF.left.toInt(), rectF.top.toInt(), rectF.right.toInt(), rectF.bottom.toInt()))
        return region
    }
```

You can call this function directly on your `Rect`:

```
val region: Region = Rect(0, 459, 1080, 0).toRightRegion()
```